# linking emails to Paypal

Tags: php, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am coding a website using PHP and one answer I haven't been able to find is how I can link user accounts to that particular user's paypal account and have them be able to receive a payment for a specific amount, like ebay does.

- How can this be done?
- Where or how can I learn to do this?
- If it's possible are there any books I need to read?

Thanks for the help in advanced.

Comment: try developer.paypal.com and there are plenty for article on google !

Comment: I checked it out it says how to set it up for basic CMS or regular e-commerce, but I'm making a site like bigcartel.com you basically sell stuff there and add your email that is used for paypal and it automatically sends payments to that account.

Comment: that email is nothing but paypal account email, you can use as `merchant id`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to set up to allow my users to sell stuff.